# Always allow ADB on Android?

Tags: android, adb, rsa

Is it possible for me to set an Android Device to automatically authorize adb from any computer? I know this this is a bad idea in terms of security, but I need if it's possible. Is there a list deep in the Android internals with the RSA fingerprints?

Comment: I believe you can set this somewhere in the [Developer options](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42).

Answer (score 0):

In `userdebug` or `eng` builds you can disable `adb` authorization with `ro.adb.secure=0`. Or if your device is rooted you could just replace the `adbd` with a custom modified insecure version.

Alternatively, if by *any computer* you just mean a few computers in your immediate vicinity - it might be easier to make all these systems to use the same RSA key. Then saving that key on the device would make all these systems authorized at once.

Comment: On rooted Android 4.4.2, I transfered `~/.android/adbkey.pub` to device via bluetooth after adding `.txt` via bluetooth for security concerns then sshing to the device with `su` and `mv /pathto/bluetooth/adbkey.pub.txt` to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys/adbkey.pub` but it still asking for verification even tried to `stop adbd` before and `start adbd` after with no luck. The problem that I'm using keyboard & mouse and can't use MicroUSB in OTG mode with ADB mode in the same time.Do you have any idea How can I getride that?

Answer (score -1):

No, for security you cannot automatically authorize any future device.

The best way is to check the box to save the RSA key when you authorize a device so that it will always be authorized on that particular computer.